# How type casting in golang works?

Tags: performance, go, types, casting

My problem statement is to load and save binary files with numbers and these numbers can be easily stored in `uint32/float32`. This gonna be around more than 2GB on disk and all need to be on memory too.

My program will require a lot of mathematical operations and golang standard libraries functions/methods require `int/float64` parameters, and I have to cast my numbers to `int/float64`

A simple benchmark ( https://play.golang.org/p/A52-wBo3Z34 ) test gave the following output :

```
$: go test -bench=. 
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
pkg: gotrade
BenchmarkCast-4             1000       1519964 ns/op
BenchmarkNoCast-4           3000        373340 ns/op
PASS
ok      gotrade 2.843s
```

This clearly show that type casting is quite expensive.

Demerits of int and float64 :

- it requires almost the double memory

Merits of int and float64 :

- avoids lot of type casting operations

Please suggest me a way to deal with this situation, am I missing something here ?

Should we always opt for `int` and `float64`, if we require external computations via standard libraries ?

Comment: it's impossible to see what it is that you might want to change when there is no source code.  For example, it might be that the "casting" (actually Go doesn't have this) should happen once at the top of your function and that you are applying it to every operation.  But that's speculation!   We don't know and can't know.  If you want a proper answer then devise a simple case that shows the problem you are having

Comment: I have added my benchmark code in go playground, and also shared a link for it, https://play.golang.org/p/A52-wBo3Z34

Comment: From my perspective, you should first [do some profiling](https://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs) before you even start to begin benchmarking. It does not make sense to benchmark the faster parts of your program, but the choking points.

Comment: thanks for the profiling suggestion , I will look into it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several mistakes in your logic, your benchmark and your assumptions.

As for the casting, your results show that your for loop is run 1000 times. Since you loop 1M times, that actually makes 1 billion casting operations... not too shabby.

Actually, I have reworked your code a bit:

```
const (
    min = float64(math.SmallestNonzeroFloat32)
    max = float64(math.MaxFloat32)
)

func cast(in float64) (out float32, err error) {

    // We need to guard here, as casting from float64 to float32 looses precision
    // Therefor, we might get out of scope.
    if in < min {
        return 0.00, fmt.Errorf("%f is smaller than smallest float32 (%f)", in, min)
    } else if in > max {
        return 0.00, fmt.Errorf("%f is bigger than biggest float32 (%f)", in, max)
    }

    return float32(in), nil
}

// multi64 uses a variadic in parameter, in order to be able
// to use the multiplication with arbitrary length.
func multi64(in ...float64) (result float32, err error) {

    // Necessary to set it to 1.00, since float64's null value is 0.00...
    im := float64(1.00)

    for _, v := range in {
        im = im * v
    }

    // We only need to cast once.
    // You DO want to make the calculation with the original precision and only
    // want to do the casting ONCE. However, this should not be done here - but in the
    // caller, as the caller knows on how to deal with special cases.
    return cast(im)
}

// multi32 is a rather non-sensical wrapper, since the for loop
// could easily be done in the caller.
// It is only here for comparison purposes.
func multi32(in ...float32) (result float32) {
    result = 1.00
    for _, v := range in {
        result = result * v
    }
    return result
}

// openFile is here for comparison to show that you can do
// a... fantastic metric ton of castings in comparison to IO ops.
func openFile() error {
    f, err := os.Open("cast.go")
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Error opening file")
    }
    defer f.Close()

    br := bufio.NewReader(f)
    if _, _, err := br.ReadLine(); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Error reading line: %s", err)
    }

    return nil
}
```

With the following testcode

```
func init() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UTC().UnixNano())
}
func BenchmarkCast(b *testing.B) {
    b.StopTimer()

    v := rand.Float64()
    var err error

    b.ResetTimer()
    b.StartTimer()

    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        if _, err = cast(v); err != nil {
            b.Fail()
        }
    }
}

func BenchmarkMulti32(b *testing.B) {
    b.StopTimer()

    vals := make([]float32, 10)

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        vals[i] = rand.Float32() * float32(i+1)
    }

    b.ResetTimer()
    b.StartTimer()

    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        multi32(vals...)
    }
}
func BenchmarkMulti64(b *testing.B) {

    b.StopTimer()

    vals := make([]float64, 10)
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        vals[i] = rand.Float64() * float64(i+1)
    }

    var err error
    b.ResetTimer()
    b.StartTimer()

    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        if _, err = multi64(vals...); err != nil {
            b.Log(err)
            b.Fail()
        }
    }
}

func BenchmarkOpenFile(b *testing.B) {
    var err error
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        if err = openFile(); err != nil {
            b.Log(err)
            b.Fail()
        }
    }
}
```

You get something like this

```
BenchmarkCast-4         1000000000           2.42 ns/op
BenchmarkMulti32-4       300000000           5.04 ns/op
BenchmarkMulti64-4       200000000           8.19 ns/op
BenchmarkOpenFile-4         100000          19591 ns/op
```

So, even with this relatively stupid and non optimized code, the perpetrator is the openFile benchmark.

Now, let us put this into perspective. 19,562ns equals to 0,019562 milliseconds. The average human can perceive latencies of about 20 milliseconds. So even those 100,000 (*"one hundred thousand"*) file openings, line reads and file closes are about 1000 times faster than a human can perceive.

Casting, compared to this is several ***orders of magnitude*** faster - so cast all you like, your bottleneck will be I/O.

### Edit

Which leaves the question why you do not import the values as float64 the first place?

Comment: Thanks for the time you took to write the beautiful explanation.
Which leaves the question why you do not import the values as float64 the first place?
As I said, my values will never be be above float32, using float64 is doubling my memory , 2GB to 4GB .
And also 1 million casting not gonna happen in my real problem, but I just did bench-marking to see if casting really takes time.
WIll I be correct to assume that I should go with float32 and cast to float64 whenever I need, as it not gonna affect much, until I am hungry for milliseconds?

Comment: @mkmayank It doubles the RAM from 2 to 4 GB? So what? And even if you do not have the RAM locally: An instance with 16GB on AWS is 20 cents / h. Just my two cents (pun intended).

Comment: yeah, it is 2018, not 90s and memory is too cheap than CPU time, thanks anyway